# driver.launch resets the App in Appium

Tags: android, appium, cucumber-jvm

I have BDD framework and i want to install the build only once for a suite so i have return the below script on driverSetUp

```
if (fullReset) {
            capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "true");
            capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "false");
        } else {
            capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
            capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        }
```

And In runner class the "fullReset" is set as true using before class

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startAppiumServer() {
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
    service.start();
    driverSetUp(false);
}
```

And In the hooks class fullReset is passed as false

```
 @Before
public void startDriver(){
    // passing the fullreset as false so that driver won't to reset or reinstall
    setUp(false);
}
```

One of the test scenario where app need to be killed and relaunched and used the below snippet

```
driver.closeApp();
driver.launchApp();
```

closeApp() pushed the app in background. And launchApp() reinstall the app but for the test scenario it shouldn't reset the app (I mean maintain the previous state whether its logged in or not).

Found the issue that its because of i am passing "True" in BeforeClass to install the app only once in the suite.

So any help would be appreciated.

thanks

driver setup code is below

```
public void setUp(boolean fullReset) {
    if (driver == null || driver.getSessionId() == null) {
        File[] app = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator
                + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator
                + "resources" + File.separator + "app").listFiles();
        for (File item : app) {
            if (!(item.isHidden())) {
                appPath = item.getAbsoluteFile();
            }
        }
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", getDeviceDetails("adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release"));
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", getDeviceDetails("adb shell getprop net.bt.name"));
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", getDeviceDetails("adb shell getprop ro.product.model"));
        capabilities.setCapability("app", appPath);
        if (i==0) {
            capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "true");
            capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "false");
        } else {
            capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
            capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        }
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "*****");
        capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity",
                "*****");
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: you are passing false in BeforeClass  as shown in above code? and only thing i m getting from your question is you want to maintain application state and not install again and again is it right ?

Comment: also can show your all capabilities how you are using it

Comment: Jitesh, i have edited the question with the capabilities Please take a look

Comment: do you mean  you want to maintain application state and not install again and again is it right  ?

Comment: Yes Jitesh, I don't want to install again